# AVSpeechSynthesisVoice Read From Button Label

Tags: ios, swift

I am wondering how to get the AVSpeechSynthesisVoice to read text from a button. I am rather new to Swift. However, I have the following reading from a string:

```
@IBAction func btnOption1Audio(sender: UIButton)
    {
        myUtterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: "Hola")
        myUtterance.rate = 1
        synth.speakUtterance(myUtterance)
        myUtterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "es-ES")

    }
```

But when I change it to something like this (reading the button text), it won't work. I am sure it is just a syntax issue though:

```
@IBAction func btnOption1Audio(sender: UIButton)
    {
        myUtterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: btnOption1Tap.titlelabel.text)
        myUtterance.rate = 1
        synth.speakUtterance(myUtterance)
        myUtterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "es-ES")

    }
```

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear from your code what `btnOption1Tap` is.  If it is an `@IBOutlet` to a `UIButton`, then you still have some issues.

`titleLabel` is a property that returns an *Optional* `UILabel`.  It must be unwrapped before being used.  Likewise, the `text` property of `UILabel` returns an *Optional* `String` which also must be unwrapped.  You'd need to do something like:

```
if let buttontext = btnOption1Tap.titleLabel?.text {
    myUtterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: buttontext)
    myUtterance.rate = 1
    synth.speakUtterance(myUtterance)
    myUtterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "es-ES")
}
```

You probably want to speak the text associated with the `UIButton` that is the `sender`.  In that case, you could just use the `currentTitle` property of `UIButton` and use the *nil coalescing operator* `??` to safely unwrap the *Optional* `String`:

```
myUtterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: sender.currentTitle ?? "")
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, it is very much appreciated. I am going to give it a try now. I'm very new to swift, so it's a lot to take in :)